# SQL Injection Error from Checkmarx using AddInParameter method in database command to add parameter query from a resx file in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, security, sql-injection, checkmarx

This is my code:

```
DataTable proposedDealTable = new DataTable();

if (accountGroupList != null && accountGroupList.Count > 0)
{
    Database database = SqlServerUtility.CreateDatabase();

    string sqlQuery = DealQueries.GetTestExpanded + " ";
    sqlQuery += DealQueries.GetTestExpandedWhereClauseCashBalances;

    string inClause = CommonUtility.ConvertListToCsvString(accountGroupList.ConvertAll(c => c.i_account_group_id.ToString()));
    sqlQuery = sqlQuery.Replace("@i_account_group_id_list", inClause);

    DbCommand dbCommand = database.GetSqlStringCommand(sqlQuery.Replace("testSchemaName",
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SchemaName"].ToString()));

    database.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@s_row_insrt", DbType.DateTime2, localDayStartTimeInUtc);
    database.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@localdate", DbType.DateTime2, localdate.Date);
    database.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@dealtype", DbType.String, DealTypesClassification.IF);

    dbCommand.CommandTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SqlServerCommandTimeout"]);

    DataSet dataSet = database.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand);
    proposedDealTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
}
```

Checkmarks scan alert:

> A SQL Injection vulnerability was identified on test-home.
>
> The application's `GetDealsCBalances` method executes a SQL query with `dbCommand`, at line 92 of \Service\Access\Dao\DealsDao.cs. The application constructs this SQL query by embedding an untrusted
> string into the query without proper sanitization. The concatenated string is submitted to the database, where it is parsed and executed accordingly.
> An attacker would be able to inject arbitrary syntax and data into the SQL query, by crafting a malicious payload and providing it via the input request; this input is then read by the GetDeals method at line 59 of \Services\Imple\CService.cs. This input then flows through the code, into a query and to the database server - without sanitization. This may enable an SQL Injection attack.

Is it a code issue? Or is it a check marks scan issue? Please suggest if the code needs to be changed.

Comment: Part of the issue is using EntLib Data Access 18 years after it became obsolete. ADO.NET 2.0 incorporated the factory model in .NET itself. The question's code replaces placeholders in the query string with various text so yes, it's possible to cause SQL injection or syntax errors. What if the `SchemaName` setting contained `dbo.Users; --`? Or `'RealSchema,` ? Far more suspicious is `sqlQuery.Replace("@i_account_group_id_list", inClause)`. What does `inClause contain?

Comment: You'd need less code if you just used ADO.NET. If you want to make your code provider agnostic check [ADO.NET's DbProviderFactory and DbConnection example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/obtaining-a-dbproviderfactory#creating-the-dbproviderfactory-and-dbconnection).

Comment: Modern micro-ORMs like [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) can reduce the code to just a single line though *and* map the results to objects. `var sales=connection.Query<Sale>("SELECT * from Sales where Region=@region and categoryID in (@categories)",new {Region="Blah", categories=new[]{1,5,8})`. It will generate a parameterized query automatically *and* safely expand the category values in the `IN` clause. There are query builder libraries that can safely create queries at runtime too